# Why does Go treat a Postgresql numeric & decimal columns as []uint8?

Tags: postgresql, go, postgresql-9.4

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Go or just something I don't understand. I have the following:

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "log"
  "reflect"

  _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
  Db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=yoitsme password=openupitsme host=x.x.x.x dbname=mydb")
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }
  rows, err := Db.Query("SELECT 1.3250::numeric, 8.548::decimal, 908.234::float, 1234::integer")
  defer rows.Close()
  for rows.Next() {
    var col1, col2, col3, col4 interface{}
    if err := rows.Scan(&col1, &col2, &col3, &col4); err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(col1, reflect.TypeOf(col1))
    log.Println(col2, reflect.TypeOf(col2))
    log.Println(col3, reflect.TypeOf(col3))
    log.Println(col4, reflect.TypeOf(col4))
  }
  if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }

}
```

This prints:

```
2015/08/11 09:35:47 [49 46 51 50 53 48] []uint8
2015/08/11 09:35:47 [56 46 53 52 56] []uint8
2015/08/11 09:35:47 908.234 float64
2015/08/11 09:35:47 1234 int64
```

So, I get []uint8 (e.g. a string) for the first two columns that are actually numbers. The last 2 columns are as expected. According to Postgresql [Numeric & Decimal types are part of the SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html). So, why doesn't Go follow the SQL standard in their database/sql package? Is it because Go doesn't have a builtin "Decimal" type? It seems wrong that the database/sql package turned a number into a string because of a shortcoming in the language....

Comment: You don't have any byte slices... Your output says `[]uint8` which is a small unsigned integer. A byte slice would be `[]byte`.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal...ahh, yes. Thx! I have updated the post.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: [byte is just an alias for uint8](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types), example: http://play.golang.org/p/2_VGNX6DmV

Comment: @JimB ah I see `[49 46 51 50 53 48] = "1.3250"`. Well that makes sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because there is no better solution. (At least wasn't until [Go 1.5's `big.Float`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float)). What other alternatives are there?

- Turn it into an integer. Obviously a bad solution since numerics can have a fractional part.
- Turn it into a `float64`. This is *evil*. Especially if you're working with money (where types like `numeric` and `decimal` have the most usage).

This particular database driver chooses instead to return a string containing the number - to let *you* decide, whether to lose some precision (by converting it into a `float64` with `strconv`) or use a decimal/precise number library (like `gmp` or `math/big`).

Comment: It just seems like a bad solution to turn it into a string b/c of a shortcoming in Go.

Comment: @kristen I wouldn't consider it a shortcoming of Go. None of those larger/higher precision numeric types are natives in any language. It's the Postgresql driver's author who made that decision. If they wanted to do something more sensible they could have provided a couple of types in Go to host their types that don't have compatible natives.

Comment: `big.Float` is a binary float and not a good fit to represent numbers with a fixed decimal precision.

Comment: Actually, PostgreSQL sends `numeric` and `decimal` as text on the wire unless you use the binary protocol options.  So the Go driver just isn't converting what PostgreSQL sends into anything else, because there's no appropriate native type. It is doing the correct thing here and should only do something else if/when Go gets a native arbitrary-precision decimal floating point data type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an issue with the answer to that questions from the developers: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/648

> It's not safe to use a float64 type for a decimal because floats can't represent all decimals. For example, decimals support exponents much larger than floats, and the coefficients of floats, when converted to their base-2 representation, will change. It is trivial in go to convert a string to a float, so we are going to keep this behavior.